# Selectize scroll event

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

The question is simple. How do I catch selectize input scroll event. For example, I want an alert box pop up each time the user scrolls down in the

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ragulka/3n2CP/4/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=3n2CP

Comment: hi Edgar,i recommend you to see this [link](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)  Selectize is the hybrid of a textbox and <select> box. It's jQuery-based and it's useful for tagging, contact lists, country selectors, and so on.

Comment: Hi) Well, this is the official doc. I've read 100 times at least) Nothing on scroll event

Comment: I am going to use it with lazy pagination to create a Facebook-like search option with some fancy rendering of options. And by the way a bit off-topic, I am in doubt as to whether selectize is first-choice option for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
{% load selectize_tags %}
<html>
 <head>  
 {% selectize_tags_media 'css' %}
 </head>
 <body>
  <label for="select-country">Country:</label>
  <select id="select-country" placeholder="Select a country...">
   <option value="">Select a country...</option>
   <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
   ....
  </select>
  ...

  {% selectize_tags_media 'js' 'jquery' %}
  <script>
   $('#select-country').selectize();
  </script>
 </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Wow, there's a selectize app for Django?? And how did you know I am using Django on server-side ???

Comment: glad to help you , i didn't knew ;)